# Alternative way to Pascal's triangle using user defined functions

Tags: c

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <conio.h>

   int fact(int x);
   int coeff(int y);

   int main(){
     int n,i,j,k;
     printf("\nENTER THE POWER:");
     scanf("%d",&n);
     for (i=0;i<=n;i++){
       for(k=n;k>i;k--){
          printf("  ");
       }
       printf("%4d",coeff(i));
       printf("\n");
     }
     getch();
   }

   int fact(int x){
      int a , f=1 ;
      for (a=x;a>0;a--){
        if(x==0){
           return 1;
        }
        return f*=a;
      }
   }

   int coeff(int y){
      int m ;
      for(m=0;m<=y;m++) {
        return (fact(y))/(fact(m)*fact(y-m));
      }
   }
```

I am a newbee in C programming . I have recently started printing patterns using C . I did the above coding of **Pascal's Triangle** myself . But my code doesn't give the correct answer  in the **CODE BLOCKS** editor . I know that there are solutions to this in websites . But I want to develop my own reasonings(though it is oddly long ) . But I'm unable to find the fault here . Would someone kindly help me ?

THANKS ...

Comment: One thing I noticed right off the bat: the return inside a for loops (both"fact()" and "coeff()") looks suspicious...  SUGGESTION: Single step through the code in a debugger.  Learning to use the debugger is one of the most important things in learning any programming language.  Honest!

Comment: @paulsm4...  How do I use a "debugger"?  Is it included in the editor **CODE BLOCKS** ?

Comment: You absolutely need to learn how to use your compiler's debugger.  It's a crucial skill.  Honest.  Look here: http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Debugging_with_Code::Blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution below consists of correcting the errors in code along with some improvements:
1) Use `getchar` from `stdio.h` instead of `getch` from the non-standard`conio.h`.
2) The `coeff` function does not need a `for` loop.
3) The `fact` function calculates the factorial completely and only then returns the value.
4) Another `for` loop included in the main to print all the coefficients of a power in one line.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fact(int x);
int coeff(int n, int y);

int main(){
 int n,i,j,k;
 n = i = j = k = 0;
 printf("\nENTER THE POWER:");
 scanf("%d",&n);
 for (i=0;i<=n;i++){
   for(k=n;k>i;k--){
      printf("  ");       
   }
   for(j=0;j<=i;j++){
    printf("%4d",coeff(i, j));
   }       
   printf("\n");
 }     
 getchar();
}

int fact(int x){
  int a , f=1 ;
  if(x==0){
       return 1;
    }
  for (a=x;a>0;a--){
    f*=a;
  }
  return f;
}

int coeff(int n, int y){
    return (fact(n))/(fact(y)*fact(n-y));
}
```

Output:

```
a.exe
ENTER THE POWER:5
             1
           1   1
         1   2   1
       1   3   3   1
     1   4   6   4   1
   1   5  10  10   5   1

a.exe
ENTER THE POWER:6
               1
             1   1
           1   2   1
         1   3   3   1
       1   4   6   4   1
     1   5  10  10   5   1
   1   6  15  20  15   6   1

a.exe
ENTER THE POWER:7
                 1
               1   1
             1   2   1
           1   3   3   1
         1   4   6   4   1
       1   5  10  10   5   1
     1   6  15  20  15   6   1
   1   7  21  35  35  21   7   1
```

Comment: Thanks!  That really helped a lot!